# loading javascript function on start using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript function here for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function onLoadFunctions() {
        //some funcitons here...    
  }
</script>
```

And I wanted to load this function when the page loads using only javascript.
Can anyone help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand what you're asking you probably want to use `window.onload`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function onLoadFunctions() {
    //some funcitons here...    
  }
  window.onload = onLoadFunctions;
</script>
```

Comment: please use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) to do this, not `window.onload` (also check the "Legacy Internet Explorer and attachEvent" section)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `body onload` event:

```
<body onload="onLoadFunctions();" ...>
  ...
</body>
```

Comment: Most likely the use of the onload attribute, rather than delegation with javascript. Twasn't me that dv'd though.

Answer (score 1):

The window has an "onload" event which you can listen to with:

```
window.addEventListener("load",myOnLoadFunction)
```

Though for more cross-browser compatibility, you may want a function like the below, as older IE versions use `.attachEvent` instead of `.addEventListener`

```
function addEvent(obj,evnt,func)
{
    if(typeof func !== 'function')
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(typeof obj.addEventListener == 'function')
    {
        return obj.addEventListener(evnt.replace(/^on/,''), func, false);
    }
    else if(typeof obj.attachEvent == 'function' || typeof obj.attachEvent == 'object')
    {
        return obj.attachEvent(evnt,func);
    }
}
```

Then call:

```
addEvent(window,'onload',myOnLoadFunction);
```

Comment: Why do you have to check if typeof attachEvent is object?

Comment: @bfavaretto That's what IE8 & IE7 return (IE8/7 mode in IE9 does, anyway)

Comment: Argh! I didn't know that, usually I just check if attachEvent exists.

Comment: @bfavaretto Yea, to be fair I could probably change it to `if(obj.attachEvent)`, but this code is from a while ago when I was more inclined to add specificity, and it's always better to be safe than sorry! Although, I'd hope noone's setting window.attachEvent to a number/string lol

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to do this:

You can add the event listener in Javascript.

```
window.addEventListener('load',myOnLoadFunction);
```

Or if you want you can add the event listener at the html tag.

```
<body onload="onLoadFunctions();">
```

**Update**

You can read more about addEventListener [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).